# How to fetch user profile from google after login

Tags: python, django, google-api

In my django project i create a function which redirect to user  on google and ask for login by google account and user can login but it didn't know to fetch user profile from google and save in my database.So any can tell me what should i have to written in if part.

```
def login(self,request):
    if (data):
        pass
    else:    
        client_id = settings.GP_CLIENT_ID
        scope = "profile&response_type=code&state=jJzexptNPLLF&flowName=GeneralOAuthFlow"
        url = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth/identifier?client_id="+client_id+"&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8000/index/&scope="+scope
        return redirect(url)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly suggest you to use [django-allauth](https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/) instead. Avoid custom login solutions especially when there are maintained ones.

Comment: I use but sometimes  django-allauth modification is difficult

Comment: At first it might seem overwhelming but its nothing to really be scared of, just spend more time with it. Its totally worth it.